# How to do unidimension test for graded response model?

Tags: r, item-response-theory

Is there any method or R function can be used to check whether data is unidimensional with graded response model (grm)?

Comment: This is often done using confirmatory factor analysis, for which you can use the lavaan package, or the openMx package. E.g. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Matthias_Ziegler/publication/287359151_Testing_the_Unidimensionality_of_Items/links/5698cf5008aea2d743771c23/Testing-the-Unidimensionality-of-Items.pdf

Comment: Why not use irt method to do cfa? It's hard to believe no function such as `ltm::unidimtest` for grm.